# How to make one column value fixed and showing result based on that column in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(DATA.LICLVS, 5) = '99999' 
            THEN 'Priority 2' 
            ELSE  'Priority 1' 
    END AS Type, 
    COUNT (distinct LIVUID) as userh1 
FROM
    DATA 
WHERE 
    UPPER(LIVUID) <> 'ADMIN' 
    AND TRIM(LIVUID) IS NOT NULL 
    AND UPPER(LIVUID) <> 'ICMADMIN' 
    AND UPPER(LIVUID) <> 'CONTINGENC' 
    AND UPPER(LIVUID) <> 'INDEXUPDAT'   
    AND LOCALDATA.LICRTD = '20211122' 
    AND LIVUID <> ''
    AND CASE WHEN VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CREATETS) + CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'HH24') = '09' 
    AND (CAST(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CREATETS) + CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'MI') AS DECIMAL(8,2))  <= 29) THEN 1 END = 1
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(DATA.LICLVS, 5) = '99999' 
            THEN 'Priority 2' 
            ELSE 'Priority 1' 
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CREATETS) + CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'HH24') = '09' 
             AND (CAST(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CREATETS) + CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'MI') AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) >= 0 
             AND CAST(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CREATETS) + CURRENT TIMEZONE, 'MI') AS DECIMAL(8,2))  <= 29) 
           THEN 1 
    END
```

I am getting the result as attached, I want to make the Type column fixed that is Priority 1 and Priority 2 and based on it I want to display userh1.

Even if userh1 is not there for Priority 1, it should show 0.

Right now, it is grouping based on Priority 1 and Priority 2 , and if userh1 is not there for Priority1, it is not showing, that row.

Your assistance is very much appreciated. Thanks

[When 'HH24'=01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4X4D.png)

[When 'HH24'=09](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U67iI.png)

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Yeah, doing group by is resulting like this. So what shall i do to resolve this? Can you help.

Comment: Please show sample data as well as desired results - which illustrate the different scenarios.

Comment: `VARCHAR_FORMAT` No such function in tsql so it seems you are using a different database engine.

Comment: `VARCHAR_FORMAT` is DB2, maybe?

Comment: Yes correct, I am using DB2

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of values you need to always be in the output, you can specify them as a subquery and then do a left join.

```
SELECT v.[type], COALESCE(SUM(q.[userh1]), 0) as [userh1]
FROM 
    (VALUES ('Priority 1'),('Priority 2')) v ([type])
    LEFT JOIN (

        /* your query here */

        ) q ON q.[type] = v.[Type]
GROUP BY v.[Type]
ORDER BY v.[Type];
```